# Why is it more secure to prohibit the DTD when consuming web services with things like .Net WCF?

Tags: wcf, web-services, security

In the documentation for securely consuming web services with WCF they state that it is recommended that you prohibit the DTD when consuming the metadata. Why is the DTD a security risk?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734741.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335713.aspx

> The easiest way to defend against all types of XML entity attacks is
>   to simply disable altogether the use of inline DTD schemas in your XML
>   parsing objects. This is a straightforward application of the
>   principle of attack surface reduction: if you’re not using a feature,
>   turn it off so that attackers won’t be able to abuse it.

Comment: :o) Thanks, I just had a friend of mine send me the same article. It is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

In this case there is a known denial of service exploit (see andrews answer)

However, almost anything that reduces the attack surface will improve the security.